# Retrieving data from Firebase DB and storing in local variable: Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app stores user location data in `Firebase Realtime Database`. What I intend to do is retrieve some of that data and process it within my app. I am able to fetch the desired data from Firebase DB (checked through debugging). Now I want to store data in local variables. I am able to store all the values except one value (Debugger shows it value to be null, though it is present in `datasnapshot`.). Data from Firebase is in `UserDataLocation` object form and following is the class for the same:

**`UserDataLocation` class:**

```
public class UserLocationData {

    String mobile, name, latitude, longitude, proximity, connection_limit, last_updated;

    public UserLocationData() {
    }

    public UserLocationData(String mobile, String name, String latitude, String longitude, String proximity, String connection_limit, String last_updated) {

        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.proximity = proximity;
        this.connection_limit = connection_limit;
        this.last_updated = last_updated;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getProximity() {
        return proximity;
    }

    public void setProximity(String proximity) {
        this.proximity = proximity;
    }

    public String getConnection_limit() {
        return connection_limit;
    }

    public void setConnection_limit(String connection_limit) {
        this.connection_limit = connection_limit;
    }

    public String getLast_updated() {
        return last_updated;
    }

    public void setLast_updated(String last_updated) {
        this.last_updated = last_updated;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am retrieving and storing the data:

```
                   @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            userLocationData = child.getValue(UserLocationData.class);
                            String connectionKey = child.getKey();

                            if (!connectionKey.equals(currentUserMobile)) {

                                for (int count = 0; count <= Integer.parseInt(connections_limit); count++) {

                                    **String last_updated = userLocationData.last_updated;** //this is showing null in debugger

                                    Location connectionLocation = getLocationFromLatLng(userLocationData.latitude, userLocationData.longitude);

                                  {......}
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

All variable except `String last_updated = userLocationData.last_updated;` is having value.

Can anyone help me resolve this???

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved my problem. The error was petty but significant. Actually, I was using `last updated` as key to store last updated time. The problem was with the format of this key. It should have been `last_updated` or something else but seems like firebase DB considers keys with `spaces` invalid. So, I changed my key to `last_updated` and problem solved.

Hope it helps someone.